# Не выполняется условие при вызове алерта

Tags: xcode, objective-c

Я вызываю алерт, и не могу написать условие, тоесть пишу, а оно не выполняеться.
Помогите.

```
(IBAction)pushBtn:(id)sender
{
    UIAlertView *alertNNumber = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"6 lvl" message:@"Enter Range number \n from 1 till 100 000" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Enter" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [alertNNumber setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
    UITextField *alertTextFi = [alertNNumber textFieldAtIndex:0];
    [alertTextFi setDelegate:self];
    [alertTextFi setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
    [alertNNumber setTag:1];
    [alertNNumber show];    
}

  (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonAlertIndex
{
    if (alertView.tag ==1)
    {

        temp6LvlAlertTextStr= [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0]text];
        temp6LvlAlertTextInt = [temp6LvlAlertTextStr intValue];

     if (temp6LvlAlertTextInt >=0 && temp6LvlAlertTextInt>100000)
       // не выполняеться условие, ничего не происходит, алерт не выскакивает.

  {                
            UIAlertView *wrongLvl6Number = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Wrong Number" message:@"Please Try Again" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Retry" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

        [wrongLvl6Number setTag:2];
        [wrongLvl6Number show];
   }
   else 
       { 
        //выполняеться всё что надо 
       }
};
```

я хотел сделать проверку, чтоб небыло пустого поля, ни нуля, не больше заданного значения.

```
введите код здесь
```

Comment: попробуй просто дебажить, ставь бряки и смотри на свои переменные при проверке, серьезно, ты проанализировав входящие данные с условием поймешь в чем проблема.

upd: я видел, что проблема решена,но! это не стеб, я серьезно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо не нашел :)

Смотри: У тебя логическая ошибка И, а должно быть ИЛИ:

```
if (temp6LvlAlertTextInt <=0 || temp6LvlAlertTextInt > 100000)
```

Вставь так, все заработает.

Просто совет: Не удобно, если я введу не верное значение, Первый Алерт исчезнет и появится второйАлерт, а потом исчезает и второй - НЕ возвращаясь к первому. Если это принципиально, то я бы в обработке НажатияАлерта добавил:

```
    if (alertView.tag == 2) {
        [self pushBtn:self];
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо. по поводу alertView.tag==2 я так и задумал делать))) 
кароче теперь всё работает.